# Highlight text in Pdf file on mouse selection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have pdf files on my server. I want to select some text (lines) with mouse and store that particular text into database for make text highlight.

Please share your experience.

Comment: did you try any code

Comment: No, i have no idea, how to do that.

Comment: to store some data in the database, you need some database application or create some interface

Comment: Yes, i will do that as i am using mysql for that. But first i need to select text in pdf and make a button after leave the selection says "Highlight text" with yes or no.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this for pdfs

Answer (score 0):

use annotator.js. and here is the sample using Front End: Angular 7 annotator.js and Backend: Spring Boot MySQL.

https://github.com/SivasankarThalavai/pdf-highlight-annotator-ui and https://github.com/SivasankarThalavai/pdf-highlight-annotator-service

Just a Sample POC.

Comment: don't just put a link in your answer explain a bit in answer and for reference add the link.